# cell2mat eliminating a column from cell array when performing conversion

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

I have the following code:

```
% Code to import data from .csv files into cell arrays called strain_trans_data, strain_ax_data, and load_data

strain_trans_data = cell2mat(strain_trans_data);
strain_trans_data = strain_trans_data*-1; % trans strain to -trans strain
strain_ax_data = cell2mat(strain_ax_data);
load_data = cell2mat(load_data);
new_trans_data = [];
new_ax_data = [];
new_load_data = [];
regressions = {'File name','y-int axial','slope axial','y-int trans','slope trans','v'};

% Rest of the code...
```

The code imports data from some .csv files which I analyze by performing a linear regression. To perform the linear regression and to plot the data, I need to convert the cell arrays to matrices. When I import a lot of data (from more than 10 .csv, in my case I have 11 files), `strain_trans_data = cell2mat(strain_trans_data);` and `strain_ax_data = cell2mat(strain_ax_data);` work fine, they just convert the cell arrays to matrices. Since there are 11 sets of data, the cell arrays are `nx11` and the final matrices are `nx11`.

For some reason, `load_data = cell2mat(load_data);` instead eliminates one column so the initial cell array is `nx11` and the final matrix is `nx10` instead. I tried with other sets of data (smaller than 10) and this problem seems to only occur in this instance. What is strange is that both `strain_trans_data = cell2mat(strain_trans_data);` and `strain_ax_data = cell2mat(strain_ax_data);` work fine, it's only the last conversion that gives a problem. Any idea why this might be happening?

Edit: I tried stepping into the cell2mat function to see what was happening and found the step where the problem happens. In the image below `m` is a `nx11 cell`

[image: Everything is fine]

then for some reason it changes to a `nx10 double`. Could there be a problem with the data in the cell array?

[image: What happened?]

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the cell array that you input into `cell2mat` I can only guess, but my guess would be that you have a column in the cell array with empty cells.

I can reproduce your issue this way:

```
C = num2cell(magic(4));
[C{:,3}] = deal([]);
```

`C` now looks like this:

```
C =
  4×4 cell array
    [16]    [ 2]    []    [13]
    [ 5]    [11]    []    [ 8]
    [ 9]    [ 7]    []    [12]
    [ 4]    [14]    []    [ 1]
```

Now we apply `cell2mat`:

```
A = cell2mat(C);
```

`A` looks like this:

```
A =
    16     2    13
     5    11     8
     9     7    12
     4    14     1
```

`C` as a 4x4 cell array, `A` is a 4x3 numeric array.